# Regex with ? for a set of words

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I want to have a regex for NAME;NAME;NAME and also for NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME where the fourth occurrence of NAME is optional.

I have one regex as (.+);(.+);(.+) which matched the first pattern but not the second. I tried playing with ? but its not working out with (.+);(.+);(.+)(;(.+))?
Basically, I want to achieve the fourth (.+) as zero or one occurence.

Comment: Dot `.` can represent/match any character including `;` which can complicate things. Instead of `.*` you could use negation of `;` like `[^;]+`. Anyway proper solution depends on what your real goal is (which we don't know about). Maybe simpler option would be splitting on `;` or using CSV parser with `;` as delimiter.

Comment: You can also use `(([^;]+);){2,4}([^;]+)`. `(([^;]+);){2,4}` means that `(([^;]+);)` will appear atlest 2 times but less than 4 times.

Comment: I came up with ([^;]+;)?(.+);(.+);(.+) --> the issue with it is for NAME;NAME;NAME the groups will be 2,3 and 4. Any cleaner way of doing this might help. Another one as per comments is ([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+);?([^;]+)?

Comment: You need regex just for getting `boolean` result if some `String` matches it or for `groups` extraction from `String`?

Comment: groups extraction from String. also would prefer sticking with DOT.

Answer (score 3):

Using `.+` matches 1+ times any character including `;`

If you want to match 3 or 4 groups separated by a ; and not including it, you could use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^;]+` with an optional group at the end of the pattern.

```
^([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)(?:;([^;]+))?$
```

- `^` Start of string
- `([^;]+);([^;]+);([^;]+)` Capture group 1, 2 and 3 matching any char except `;`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `;([^;]+)` Match `;` and capture any char except `;` in group 4
- `)?` Close group and make it optional
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cOaaZL/1)

---

If the parts in between can not contain `;` you could also use split and count the number of the parts.

```
String arr[] = { "NAME;NAME;", "NAME;NAME;NAME", "NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME", "NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME" };

for (String s  : arr) {
    String [] parts = s.split(";");
    if (parts.length == 3 || parts.length == 4) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

Output

```
NAME;NAME;NAME
NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [regex](https://regex101.com/r/chrdbh/1), `(.+);\1;\1(?:;\1)?`

**Demo:**

```
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Test
        Stream.of(
                    "NAME;NAME;NAME", 
                    "NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME",
                    "NAME;NAME;NAME;",
                    "NAME;NAME;NAMES",
                    "NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME"
        ).forEach(s -> System.out.println(s + " => " + s.matches("(.+);\\1;\\1(?:;\\1)?")));
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
NAME;NAME;NAME => true
NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME => true
NAME;NAME;NAME; => false
NAME;NAME;NAMES => false
NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME;NAME => false
```

**Explanation of the regex:**

- `\1` matches the same text as most recently matched by the 1st capturing group.
- `?:` makes `(?:;\1)` a non-capturing group.
- `?` makes the previous token optional

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, please try following.

***1st solution:***

```
^(?:([^;]*);){2,3}\1$
```

[Online demo for 1st solution](https://regex101.com/r/cY8XsW/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^(?:        ##Matching value from starting of the value here.
  ([^;]*);  ##Creating 1st capturing group which has everything till ; in it, followed by ;.
){2,3}      ##Looking for 2 to 3 occurrences of it.
\1$         ##Again matching 1st capturing group value at the end here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:***

```
^([^;]*)(;)(?:\1\2){1,2}\1$
```

[Online demo for 2nd solution](https://regex101.com/r/YSWOQP/1)

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above.

```
^([^;]*)  ##checking from starting of value, a capturing group till value of ; is coming here.
(;)       ##Creating 2nd capturing group which has ; in it.
(?:       ##Creating a non-capturing group here.
\1\2      ##Matching 1st and 2nd capturing group here.
){1,2}    ##Closing non-capturing group here, with occurrences of 1 to 2.    
\1$   ##Matching 1st capturing group value here at the end of value.
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use lazy quantifier `+?`. Example:

```java
    private static final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("((\\w+);?)+?");

    public void extractGroups(String input) {
        var matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(2));
        }
    }
```

Input `"FIRST;SECOND;THIRD;FOURTH"` gives

```java
FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
FOURTH
```

Input `"FIRST;SECOND;THIRD"` gives

```java
FIRST
SECOND
THIRD
```

Lazy quantifier is used to match the shortest possible `String`. And if you call it repeatedly in `while` loop, you'll get all matches.
Also you should better use `\\w` for mathing words, cause `.` also includes the `;` symbol;